# Capturing OutputDebugString() calls on a server written in Delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi, outputdebugstring

I have a server written in Delphi that I would like to add a debug logger to so it can log messages passed to Windows.OutputDebugString() while it is deployed, so clients can send me the log when there are issues. In the end, I want functionality similar to [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview), but built into the server program itself.

I understand how the OutputDebugString works by writing to a shared memory file and using system wide events to synchronize the program and its debugger, and I have [found solutions in C#](http://www.michaelfcollins3.me/blog/2013/06/01/understanding-outputdebugstring.html) and [C++](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23776/Mechanism-of-OutputDebugString), but have yet to be able to translate those solutions to Delphi.

My largest problem is not knowing how to interact with the DBWIN_BUFFER_READY and DBWIN_DATA_READY synchronization events with Delphi, or how to reference the specific memory mapped file "DBWIN_BUFFER" that OutputDebugString writes to.

Additionally I have found solutions that implement their own method call instead of Windows.OutputDebugString(), but the program already has hundreds of calls, both in the code we have written and third-party modules we have added in, so these are not an option.

Comment: It is pretty much the same. What did you try?

Comment: You say you have lots of existing calls to `OutputDebugString`, and that makes it impossible to call something else. Do you not have a find-and-replace tool available?

Comment: I tried to find Delphi classes similar to C#'s MemoryMappedFile and EventWaitHandle, both of which accept a string with the name of the event/memory location that they are linked to, such as in the C# example I found. I am relatively new at Delphi, so I may simply lack the experience to find these classes.

Comment: Look at the C++ code as your guide, not the C# code. The C++ code calls ordinary Win32 API functions, and those map easily to the same functions in Delphi. See the call to `OpenFileMapping`, for instance. The C# code uses the .Net framework, which doesn't translate so well to native code.

Comment: @RobKennedy All of the third party code is already compiled and are used in parts we would like to monitor, so find/replace is not an option there. Furthermore, we would still like to be able to use DebugView or XE6's debugger to monitor these calls while not in development.

Comment: There is stock [`TEvent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SyncObjs.TEvent) and various third-party wrappers for section objects.

Comment: @ RobKennedy That makes a lot of sense. I will dig into that harder.

Comment: Another idea: Install a hook for the `OutputDebugString` API to reroute it to a function of your choosing. It would be a process-local hook, so you wouldn't have to worry about filtering messages from other processes as you would when reading the kernel's shared memory. That would be compatible with code you can't recompile to call your function directly.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ code you linked to can be translated to Delphi as follows:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//         File: WinDebugMonitor.pas
//  Description: Interface of class TWinDebugMonitor
//      Created: 2007-12-6
//       Author: Ken Zhang
//       E-Mail: cpp.china@hotmail.com
//
//   Translated: 2015-02-13
//   Translator: Remy Lebeau
//       E-Mail: remy@lebeausoftware.org
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

unit WinDebugMonitor;

interface

uses
  Windows;

type
  PDbWinBuffer = ^DbWinBuffer;
  DbWinBuffer = record
    dwProcessId: DWORD;
    data: array[0..(4096-sizeof(DWORD))-1] of AnsiChar;
  end;

  TWinDebugMonitor = class
  private
    m_hDBWinMutex: THandle;
    m_hDBMonBuffer: THandle;
    m_hEventBufferReady: THandle;
    m_hEventDataReady: THandle;

    m_hWinDebugMonitorThread: THandle;
    m_bWinDebugMonStopped: Boolean;
    m_pDBBuffer: PDbWinBuffer;

    function Initialize: DWORD;
    procedure Uninitialize;
    function WinDebugMonitorProcess: DWORD;

  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure OutputWinDebugString(const str: PAnsiChar); virtual;
  end;

implementation

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  PROPERTIES OF OBJECTS
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  NAME        |   DBWinMutex      DBWIN_BUFFER_READY      DBWIN_DATA_READY
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  TYPE        |   Mutex           Event                   Event
//  ACCESS      |   All             All                     Sync
//  INIT STATE  |   ?               Signaled                Nonsignaled
//  PROPERTY    |   ?               Auto-Reset              Auto-Reset
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

constructor TWinDebugMonitor.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  if Initialize() <> 0 then begin
    OutputDebugString('TWinDebugMonitor.Initialize failed.'#10);
  end;
end;

destructor TWinDebugMonitor.Destroy;
begin
  Uninitialize;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TWinDebugMonitor.OutputWinDebugString(const str: PAnsiChar);
begin
end;

function WinDebugMonitorThread(pData: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
var
  _Self: TWinDebugMonitor;
begin
  _Self = TWinDebugMonitor(pData);

  if _Self <> nil then begin
    while not _Self.m_bWinDebugMonStopped do begin
      _Self.WinDebugMonitorProcess;
    end;
  end;

  Result := 0;
end;

function TWinDebugMonitor.Initialize: DWORD;
begin
  SetLastError(0);

  // Mutex: DBWin
  // ---------------------------------------------------------
  m_hDBWinMutex := OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, 'DBWinMutex');
  if m_hDBWinMutex = 0 then begin
    Result := GetLastError;
    Exit;
  end;

  // Event: buffer ready
  // ---------------------------------------------------------
  m_hEventBufferReady := OpenEvent(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, 'DBWIN_BUFFER_READY');
  if m_hEventBufferReady = 0 then begin
    m_hEventBufferReady = CreateEvent(nil, FALSE, TRUE, 'DBWIN_BUFFER_READY');
    if m_hEventBufferReady = 0 then begin
      Result := GetLastError;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  // Event: data ready
  // ---------------------------------------------------------
  m_hEventDataReady := OpenEvent(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, 'DBWIN_DATA_READY');
  if m_hEventDataReady = 0 then begin
    m_hEventDataReady := CreateEvent(nil, FALSE, FALSE, 'DBWIN_DATA_READY');
    if m_hEventDataReady = 0 then begin
      Result := GetLastError;
    end;
  end;

  // Shared memory
  // ---------------------------------------------------------
  m_hDBMonBuffer := OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ, FALSE, 'DBWIN_BUFFER');
  if m_hDBMonBuffer = 0 then begin
  begin
    m_hDBMonBuffer := CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, nil, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, SizeOf(DbWinBuffer), 'DBWIN_BUFFER');
    if m_hDBMonBuffer = 0 then begin
      Result := GetLastError;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  m_pDBBuffer := PDbWinBuffer(MapViewOfFile(m_hDBMonBuffer, SECTION_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0));
  if m_pDBBuffer = nil then begin
    Result := GetLastError;
    Exit;
  end;

  // Monitoring thread
  // ---------------------------------------------------------
  m_bWinDebugMonStopped := False;

  m_hWinDebugMonitorThread := CreateThread(nil, 0, @WinDebugMonitorThread, Self, 0, nil);
  if m_hWinDebugMonitorThread = 0 then begin
    m_bWinDebugMonStopped := True;
    Result := GetLastError;
    Exit;
  end;

  // set monitor thread's priority to highest
  // ---------------------------------------------------------
  SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);
  SetThreadPriority(m_hWinDebugMonitorThread, THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);

  Result := 0;
end;

procedure TWinDebugMonitor.Uninitialize;
begin
  if m_hWinDebugMonitorThread <> 0 then begin
    m_bWinDebugMonStopped := True;
    WaitForSingleObject(m_hWinDebugMonitorThread, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(m_hWinDebugMonitorThread);
    m_hWinDebugMonitorThread := 0;
  end;

  if m_hDBWinMutex <> 0 then begin
    CloseHandle(m_hDBWinMutex);
    m_hDBWinMutex := 0;
  end;

  if m_pDBBuffer <> nil then begin
    UnmapViewOfFile(m_pDBBuffer);
    m_pDBBuffer := nil;
  end;

  if m_hDBMonBuffer <> 0 then begin
    CloseHandle(m_hDBMonBuffer);
    m_hDBMonBuffer := 0;
  end;

  if m_hEventBufferReady <> 0  then begin
    CloseHandle(m_hEventBufferReady);
    m_hEventBufferReady := 0;
  end;

  if m_hEventDataReady <> 0 then begin
    CloseHandle(m_hEventDataReady);
    m_hEventDataReady := 0;
  end;
end;

function TCWinDebugMonitor.WinDebugMonitorProcess: DWORD;
const
  TIMEOUT_WIN_DEBUG = 100;
begin
  // wait for data ready
  Result := WaitForSingleObject(m_hEventDataReady, TIMEOUT_WIN_DEBUG);

  if Result = WAIT_OBJECT_0 then begin
    OutputWinDebugString(m_pDBBuffer^.data);

    // signal buffer ready
    SetEvent(m_hEventBufferReady);
  end;
end;
```

```
program Monitor;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  WinDebugMonitor;

type
  Monitor = class(TWinDebugMonitor)
  public
    procedure OutputWinDebugString(const str: PAnsiChar); override;
  end;

procedure Monitor.OutputWinDebugString(const str: PAnsiChar);
begin
  Write(str);
end;

var
  mon: Monitor;
begin
  WriteLn('Win Debug Monitor Tool');
  WriteLn('----------------------');
  mon := Monitor.Create;
  try
    ReadLn;
  finally
    mon.Free;
  end;
end.
```

```
program Output;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils, Windows, Messages;

var
  hConsoleInput: THandle;

function KeyPressed: boolean;
var
  NumberOfEvents: Integer;
begin
  GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(hConsoleInput, NumberOfEvents);
  Result := NumberOfEvents > 0;
end;

procedure KeyInit;
var
  mode: Integer;
begin
  // get input file handle
  Reset(Input);
  hConsoleInput := TTextRec(Input).Handle;

  // checks/sets so mouse input does not work
  SetActiveWindow(0);
  GetConsoleMode(hConsoleInput, mode);
  if (mode and ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT) = ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT then
    SetConsoleMode(hConsoleInput, mode xor ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT);
end;

var
  i: Integer;
  buf: AnsiString;
begin
  KeyInit;

  WriteLn('Press any key to stop calling OutputDebugString......');

  i := 0;
  while not KeyPressed do
  begin
    Inc(i);
    buf := Format('Message from process %d, msg id: %d'#10, [ GetCurrentProcessId(), I]);
    OutputDebugStringA(PAnsiChar(buf));
  end;

  Writeln('Total ', i, ' messages sent.');
end.
```

Comment: Wow, old school `KeyPressed`!

Comment: Well, Delphi doesn't have any equivalent to C's `kbhit()`, and I didn't want to re-write the `Output` code to use a GUI.  Although I suppose I could have re-written it to use a worker thread at least and then use `ReadLn()` to wait for the termination request.

Comment: Yeah, for GUI worker thread is a must, but as a concept demonstration your translation is perfect already.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is wrong.

Hint: This function is listed under functions for debugging, and it has "Debug" in its name.

Imagine [what if two programs did this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx). OutputDebugString is a global function. It sends a string from ANY process to the debugger. If two programs would use OutputDebugString as their logging solution - you will get a mess from simultaneous output from two processes, and each log will be mixed with other.

Quote from MSDN (as additional proof that your solution is wrong):

> Applications should send very minimal debug output and provide a way for the user to enable or disable its use. To provide more detailed tracing, see Event Tracing.

In other words, OutputDebugString is a debugging solution for development builds; it is not a logging system.

Use this (pseudo-code to illustrate the idea):

```
unit DebugTools;

interface

procedure OutputDebugString(const AStr: String);

implementation

procedure OutputDebugString(const AStr: String);
begin
  if IsDebuggerPresent then
    Windows.OutputDebugString(PChar(AStr))
  else
  begin
    CritSect.Enter;
    try
      GlobalLog.Add(AStr);
    finally
      CritSect.Leave;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Just add this unit to the `uses` clause for each of your other units - and you will automatically capture "output OutputDebugString" without need to change source code.